# postgresql vacuum analyze many tables

Tags: plpgsql, postgresql-8.4, vacuum

I have a medium-size table (about 15 billion rows) that is made of roughly 200 sub-tables (i.e. each sub-table INHERITS the mother table, and there are constraint CHECKS to optimize the partitioning).

The plpgsql code that loads each table also produces indexes on each of the sub-tables, but unfortunately (because it is a function), it cannot also execute a `vacuum analyze subtable;` for the sub-table it has just loaded and indexed.

So, until the next `vacuum analyze` of the whole DB is done, all the queries on the mother table suck and don't use the indexes (as revealed by explain).

Note that this is all with PostgreSQL 8.2.14.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to have the plpgsql function say, please pretty please with sugar on top, end transaction block and perform a `vacuum analyze subtable`?
2. Is there a way to vacuum/analyze many tables at once using some wildcard (`vacuum analyze schema.subtables*`)?
3. Alternatively, is it possible to vacuum/analyze just one schema?
4. Is there any other way to vacuum/analyze the 200 sub-tables in a programmatic fashion from within postgresql (yes, I can dump the name of all sub-tables, toss and season to taste with some perl into a psql script, and execute that, but it's kinda ugly).

Answer (score 1):

> Note that this is all with PostgreSQL 8.2.14.

8.2 went out of support last year, after a five year run, and 8.2.14 is missing lots of fixes security vulnerabilities and bugs which were discovered after 2009-03-16.  You desperately need to move onto a version from this decade.

> Is there any other way to vacuum/analyze the 200 sub-tables in a
>   programmatic fashion from within postgresql (yes, I can dump the name
>   of all sub-tables, toss and season to taste with some perl into a psql
>   script, and execute that, but it's kinda ugly).

You could create entries in `pg_autovacuum` and leave it to the autovacuum daemon.  Of course, that daemon has gotten a *lot* better in recent years, so that's another reason to update.

Comment: @kgrttn Thanks for the answer. I am bound to PostgreSQL 8.2.14 because I'm using Greenplum (4.0.4.0). I know Greeplum 4.2 has been out for a few months but it's still using PostgreSQL 8.2.15, not sure it would make much of a difference.

Comment: Instead of creating the new partition as a child, loading it, and then analyzing it, why not load it and analyze it independently, and *then* use `ALTER TABLE` to make it a child after it's ready to go? I was unable to use the syntax for that in either the answer or a comment without getting an error, so I guess I have to leave it as an exercise to look that up.  :-(